# Passcode view on top of everything when app is back from background, and supports autorotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I have a simple UITabBarController-based universal app that I'm adding autorotation support on iPad, and the only thing that's giving me headaches at the moment is supporting autorotation for the PassCode view controller (XIB-based).

**Requirements:**
1- Passcode VC's view to be presented with autorotation support at the app launch (Done).
2- Passcode VC's view to be presented with autorotation support when the app is back from background (didBecomeActive:), and to be on top of everything else.

**What I tried for requirement #2:**
1- Adding the Passcode's view as a subview to the app's window (addsubview:). Works great except that autorotation doesn't work (I understand why).
2- Adding the Passcode's view as a subview to the tabbar controller's view (addsubview:). Autorotation works great, but if another view controller is being presented modally, the Passcode's view will be underneath it for sure (Also understandable).

I can see other apps implementing the exact same thing I want, like DropBox and GoodReader for example.

Any input is pretty appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many view controllers do you have to show this passcode view on?

Comment: @calvinBhai I don't quite understand your question, but the Passcode view controller's view should be presented whenever the app is launched (solved), or when it's back from the background, on top of ANY view(s) that's currently visible.

Comment: Adding the Passcode's view as a subview to the tabbar controller's view (addsubview:). Autorotation works great, but if another view controller is being presented modally, the Passcode's view will be underneath it for sure (Also understandable). People will have to go past the passcode view to do anything else right? So how does the question of presenting the modalViewController arise. When people are done interacting with your passcode view, it should be removed from superview and released. You can give that responsibility to your app delegate which is always around during the app runtime.

Comment: Create a protocol in passcodeView controller and write a method that passes itself using 'self' to appdelegate. Now make appdelegate as the delegate for passcodeView protocol. And call this method upon successful validation. It will send itself to appdelegate where you can destroy it and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you this is the best way, but we managed to get similar functionality using a separate window. We started out using this library: [Block Alerts](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets) which was a pretty good jumping off point.

This got us our new `UIWindow` that would appear on top of everything, but didn't auto-rotate very well. However, with a little experimentation, we found that the following would give us the auto rotation that we desired:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(kDefaultPortraitWidth / 2, (kDefaultPortraitHeight * 0.3f));
        containerView.center = newCenter;
    }
    else
    {
        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(kDefaultPortraitHeight / 2, (kDefaultPortraitWidth * 0.2f));
        containerView.center = newCenter;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

The container view just contained all of our 'stuff' to make it easier to move around like this.

Note: the constants aren't really important, use whatever makes your view work.